# How to call constructor when overwriting array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanted to create an array where each element can be either set from an `int` or `float` (these particular types are just an example).

So I went ahead and made a class with two constructors:

```
class ScaledNumber {
  private:
    int scaled_number;

  public:
    ScaledNumber(int number);
    ScaledNumber(float number);
};

ScaledNumber::ScaledNumber(int number) {
  scaled_number = number * 1000;
}

ScaledNumber::ScaledNumber(float number) {
  scaled_number = (int)(number * 1000);
}
```

This works fine when I work with a single variable of this class. But now I want to create an array of such objects. I had to add a third constructor to even get the declaration working:

```
ScaledNumber::ScaledNumber() {}

ScaledNumber numbers[5];
```

Now if I want to re-assign for example `numbers[3]`, can I somehow make use of the constructor or do I have to add a `set()` method or something like that?

Comment: You would usually implement an assignment operator for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I somehow make use of the constructor

You can simply use:

```
ScaledNumber numbers[5];
numbers[0] = 20;
numbers[1] = 30.2f;
```

The compiler will use the appropriate constructor before making the assignment. The last two lines are translated by the compiler to:

```
numbers[0] = ScaledNumber(20);
numbers[1] = ScaledNumber(30.2f);
```

Comment: He would need a default constructor for that to work, right?  Otherwise, what would the original array declaration use to construct all 5 elements?

Comment: ah, so desu ka (so it is)

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. Out of curiosity, (how) would that work when the constructor accepts multiple parameters?

Comment: @AndreKR, in that case, you can use `numbers[0] = ScaledNumber(arg1, arg2);`. If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you can shorten that to `numbers[0] = {arg1, arg2};`.

Comment: I would note, that it works because, c-tors are not marked as `explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of `ScaledNumber numbers[5];` anyway? You previously didn't need `ScaledNumber number;` for a single object to work, presumably because it didn't make sense to create such a half-ready object, so why would you need it for five objects?

You can just initialise the objects in the array like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class ScaledNumber {
  private:
    int scaled_number;

  public:
    ScaledNumber(int number);
    ScaledNumber(double number);
};

ScaledNumber::ScaledNumber(int number) : scaled_number(number * 1000) {
    std::cout << "int\n";
}

ScaledNumber::ScaledNumber(double number) : scaled_number(static_cast<int>(number * 1000)) {
    std::cout << "double\n";
}

int main() {
    ScaledNumber numbers[] = { 1, 2.2, 3, 4.4, 5 };
}
```

Output:

```
int
double
int
double
int
```

Note that I also made four improvements: I replaced `float` with `double` (the default floating-point type of the language), turned the C-style cast into `static_cast`, I added initialisation lists to the constructors and I made the compiler count the elements in the array.

Comment: In my library (where I have the array) I don't yet know the values. They main code takes measurements and passes them to my library which performs calculations on them when all 5 values have arrived.